# Returning pointer becomes garbage...c++

Tags: c++

```
Node* binTree::insert(vector<Node> vec, int index) {

    Node* new_node = &vec[index];
    Node* left_leaf=NULL;
    Node* right_leaf=NULL;
    if (new_node->left == -1 || new_node->right == -1)
        return new_node;
    if (c == 'n')
        {
            root = new_node;
            c = 'y';
        }
    index = new_node->left;
    new_node->left_leaf = insert(vec, new_node->left);
    index = new_node->right;
    new_node->right_leaf = insert(vec, new_node->right);
    return NULL;
};
```

My problem is that after doing the recursion process, when it hit "return new node", the returned value becomes garbage. I have no idea why, any hints or fixes?

Comment: Because you return a pointer to a *local variable*. Try passing the vector by reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_node` is referencing an element in a local variable (the `vector` is passed as copy argument). Try passing it as reference.

Comment: you mean this vector: "    new_node->left_leaf = insert(vec, new_node->left);  "?    Should I pass &vec instead?

Comment: `Node* binTree::insert(vector<Node>& vec, int index)`

Comment: BTW, `i` is `index`, isn't?

Comment: Simply `i` is not defined anywhere in the fragment of code you posted ;). I've edited your code to match it.

Comment: @john Yes a vector is not a C array. It is copied if you try to pass it (so usually vectors need to be passed by reference).

Comment: @malcolm-mclean You're right. Actually, if not used as an output parameter the best would be to use a constant reference.