# Binary tree in c++, can't figure out how to save nodes

Tags: c++

```
    Node* binTree::insert(vector<Node>& vec, int index, Node* leaf) {
    Node* new_node = &vec[index];
    Node* left_leaf=NULL;
    Node* right_leaf=NULL;
    leaf = new_node;
    if (new_node->left == -1 || new_node->right == -1)
        return NULL;
    if (c == 'n')
        {
            root = new_node;
            c = 'y';
        }
    index = new_node->left;
    new_node->left_leaf = insert(vec, new_node->left, new_node->left_leaf);
    index = new_node->right;
    new_node->right_leaf = insert(vec, new_node->right, new_node->right_leaf);
    return NULL;
};
```

So, the idea is that I should create a tree that looks like this: [image]

Where the numbers below the circles are the indices that I'm accessing through the vector. On each space of the vector there is:  the number to the left(index), to the right(index) and inside the node and all of this seem to work, what is not working is my way to connect the tree. I can't figure out how to connect the tree. It seems to traverse correctly (preorder) but have no idea where to go from here...any ideas? The idea of the recursive step also troubles me, I don't know where to return the actual left pointer

Comment: First of all, you don't return anything but `NULL`. Secondly, `leaf = new_node` doesn't do anything. useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning pointer becomes garbage...c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465790/returning-pointer-becomes-garbage-c)

Comment: I though of returning new_node at some point but I'm not sure where it the code I should be returning the actual node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i correctly understood your question, but here we go:

The only node you 'KNOW' for fact is the root, then, if you want to go to the others, you just 'find your way' through the pointers (right and Left)

Also, Here's my recursive code on the Pre-Order:

```
void pre_ordem(node *root)
{
    if(root!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%d - ",root->num);
        pre_ordem(root->left);
        pre_ordem(root->right);
    }
}
```